# Does Angular JS Pages should be requested from server

Tags: angularjs

I was getting myself started with Angular JS.

I tried to put angular code in my html page and then I tried to open up browser but Angular JS didn't worked.

But when I requested the same page from server It did worked

A bit of mystry ...

Comment: Yes, Some functions work only when accessed from server, but simple functions will work without deploying in server.

Answer (score 0):

as soon as angular need to load template code using a template url you have to serve the page via HTTP because angular can only load templates using HTTP.

one example would be :

```
<div>
  <div ng-include="'templateA.htm'"></div>
  <div ng-include="'templateB.htm'"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some directives of AngularJS use **AJAX** to load themselves and by default navigators like Chrome block AJAX request when they are local.

You can open your AngularJS app in any server e.g: [http-server](http://httpd.apache.org/)